# ASTC for normal maps

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl-es, textures, vulkan, astc

I am trying to compress my normal map textures, so I am using ASTC 4x4.

It works completely good for other textures (aka diffuse), but quality lost for normal maps were too big.

Is there a way to improve ASTCs quality directly for Normal Maps ?

I have tried to use -normal-psnr flag, but it makes my texture greyed (instead of normal blue)

ASTC normal map:

[image]

PNG normal map:

[image]

Comment: Could you illustrate what quality issues you see? Is that in-editor or on device? And what platform are you on? The tags are confusing with both Vulkan and OpenGL ES

Comment: @Bart I have attached screenshots, please look at them. My issue don't repeat on specific rendering engine, issue is inside astcenc codec, so my question is how to compress normal maps more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Compressing normal maps using a normal mode in the reference encoder stores normal maps as X+Y maps. X is stored in the R channel (and duplicated in G and B) and Y is stored in the A channel, which is why it looks grey. You need to reconstruct Z in the shader; based on the fact that the full normal should be unit length you don't need to store it which gives the compressor a lot more bits to play with to boost quality.

```
vec3 normal;
normal.xy = texture(sampler, uv).ra;
normal.xy = normal.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;
normal.z = sqrt(1 - dot(normal.xy, normal.xy));
```

I tend to find normals look OK with 5x5 blocks (5.12bpp), but much lower bitrate than that starts to hit quality problems.

Comment: can you help me, how to take the correct value from the texture ?
btw, seems sqrt(1 - dot(normal.xy, normal.xy)); will crash because of sqrt(0)

Comment: Are your normals definitely unit length before you compress them?

Comment: Note I had a typo in the shader code, that is now fixed, the texture swizzle should be `.ra` not `.rz`.